# Can't center a table in HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to center the rows in a `table` element on a page, and they won't center--and I've discovered that for some reason the `tbody` (and so, the `table`) width are expanding to the entire width of the page, so `margin: 0, auto;` will not then center the table.

Instead, the contents of the `<tr>`s end up all pushed to the left, no matter what I do.  The only way I've been able to get the table centered is do something like set the table to `width: 10px` (obviously smaller than it actually is), but then it also squishes all of its descendants and removes my control over their width, which is not desirable.

How can I get this table centered?  Happy to provide more detail as is necessary if the code isn't enough.

PHP/HTML:

```php
<table id="items" class="inventory-table center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <?php for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) { ?>
        <tr id="inventory-row-<?php echo $i ?>" class="inventory-row">
            <td class="inventory-image">
                <img src="<my image>" />
            </td>
            <td class="inventory-name">
                Classic frame
            </td>
            <td class="inventory-price">
                $<span class="price">139</span>
            </td>
            <td class="purchase-number-td">
                <span class="purchase-number"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div data-inventoryrownumber="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="arrow-up top-arrow purchase-arrow"></div>
                <div data-inventoryrownumber="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="arrow-down bottom-arrow purchase-arrow"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

SASS:

```css
/* inventory table css */

$triangle-size: 30px;

.inventory-table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inventory-row {
  display: inline-block;

  td {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.inventory-image img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

td.purchase-number-td {
  min-width: 30px;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: $triangle-size solid transparent;
  border-right: $triangle-size solid transparent;
  border-bottom: $triangle-size solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: $triangle-size solid transparent;
  border-right: $triangle-size solid transparent;
  border-top: $triangle-size solid black;
}

.top-arrow {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.bottom-arrow {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Screenshot from Chrome dev tools:

[image: Table]

Comment: the `<table>` is expanding because it  has `style="width:100%;"` as you were saying. So how do you want to center such an element? It has no space left on the sides. Please make demo to clarify  the problem.

Comment: @NicoO removing the `width=100%` changes nothing.  The table element, when I hover over it in Chrome Inspector, extends all the way from the left of the page to the right, but the child elements are still left-aligned.

Comment: Edit this demo to show your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/ATvQ8/

Comment: @NicoO I've attached a Chrome dev tools screenshot to show the issue I'm having.  As you can see, `tbody` takes up the whole screen, so the elements below aren't centered.  If you hover over the `tr`, it simply ends after the arrows.

Comment: I added a center div and it works, check for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what about adding a table_conteiner which you do can center?

I've added a div called table_container, and I've centred it using `margin: 0 auto;`. As the table is inside, is centred in your markup. I've also removed `inline-block` from the tr, as it made not possible to the td expand to fill all the row. Note that I modified the values of the PHP and SASS from the file to make it pure HTML and CSS, as it's easier to everybody to test a pure markup problem.

```
/* inventory table css */

.inventory-table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inventory-row {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.inventory-row td {
    text-align: center;
}

.inventory-image img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

td.purchase-number-td {
  min-width: 30px;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid black;
}

.top-arrow {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.bottom-arrow {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.table_container {
    width: 500px;
}

.table_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 700px
}

</style>

<div class="table_container">

    <table id="items" class="inventory-table center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr id="inventory-row-1" class="inventory-row">
                <td class="inventory-image">
                    <img src="<my image>" />
                </td>
                <td class="inventory-name">
                    Classic frame
                </td>
                <td class="inventory-price">
                    $<span class="price">139</span>
                </td>
                <td class="purchase-number-td">
                    <span class="purchase-number"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div data-inventoryrownumber="1" class="arrow-up top-arrow purchase-arrow"></div>
                    <div data-inventoryrownumber="1" class="arrow-down bottom-arrow purchase-arrow"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="inventory-row-1" class="inventory-row">
                <td class="inventory-image">
                    <img src="<my image>" />
                </td>
                <td class="inventory-name">
                    Classic frame
                </td>
                <td class="inventory-price">
                    $<span class="price">139</span>
                </td>
                <td class="purchase-number-td">
                    <span class="purchase-number"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div data-inventoryrownumber="1" class="arrow-up top-arrow purchase-arrow"></div>
                    <div data-inventoryrownumber="1" class="arrow-down bottom-arrow purchase-arrow"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="inventory-row-1" class="inventory-row">
                <td class="inventory-image">
                    <img src="<my image>" />
                </td>
                <td class="inventory-name">
                    Classic frame
                </td>
                <td class="inventory-price">
                    $<span class="price">139</span>
                </td>
                <td class="purchase-number-td">
                    <span class="purchase-number"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div data-inventoryrownumber="1" class="arrow-up top-arrow purchase-arrow"></div>
                    <div data-inventoryrownumber="1" class="arrow-down bottom-arrow purchase-arrow"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Culprit turned out to be `.inventory-row {display: inline-block; }`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the table margin, Add:
`margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: I actually had this before and added it now, and it still is not centered.  No change.

Comment: I cant understand what exactly u want to be centered

Comment: I think you've understood what I'm looking to center.  The advice you gave *should* work but *isn't* working--that's the problem I've been having.  I want the table itself as a whole to be centered, but adding `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't have an effect.

Comment: ok screenshot now talks,, try using width:200px; or <table align='center'>.. but ur problem is the table width having full width

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/rW52k/)

### HTML

```
<table>
    <th colspan='3'>header</th>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%; /* for small screens */
    max-width: 20em; /* define width while keeping it flexible */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```